# how to create a unique map and create a string list of a given attribute with stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

how can I group a list in the form of a map, with one attribute being the key to the map and the other being a list of strings?

Example:

[image]

I would like to organize it in the following way.

MAP<String,List <'String'>>

X , {A}

Y, {A}

Z, {A,B}

instead of ordering how MAP<String, List<'cartPromotion'>>

note: could you suggest complementary articles on streams with groupingBy, Function.Identify ()

Comment: as a side note, prefer sharing code as text and not image in the question.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer and the editing tip and for this suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `mapping` as the downstream collector to map the objects to one of their attributes -

```
Map<String, List<String>> groupedProducts = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(cartPromotion::getPromotion, 
                Collectors.mapping(cartPromotion::getProduct, Collectors.toList())));
```

Answer (score 0):

**This may be helpful as per your requirment:**

```
Map<String, List<String>> promotors = cartPromotionList.stream()
                .collect(
                        Collectors.groupingBy(cart -> cart.getPromotion(),
                                Collectors.mapping(cart -> cart.getProduct(),
                                        Collectors.toList())));

        promotors
                .forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " : " + v.toString()));
```